# Tab Activity first screen independent of tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a screen with 2 tabs in at the bottom of the screen.
Once I run the app, automatically first tab will be active and the activity related to that screen will be shown (Screen 1). Then when the user clicks on the second tab it opens another activity (Screen 2).

Requirement: I want to show the screen 0 when the app loads instead of showing the screen 1. At this time both the tabs should be inactive(not pressed). Once the user clicks on any tab only the respective screens should open (Screen 1 and screen 2).

How to do it?

The code I used is given below:

```
public class TabBarActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Your Tab Titles
        String tab_title[] = { "Screen 1", "Screen 2"};

        // Your Tab Drawables for their states
        int tab_drawables[] = { R.drawable.tab_home_custom,
                R.drawable.tab_balance_custom};

        // Your Tab Activities
        Object tab_act[] = { TabB.class,TabC.class};

        // / TabHost setup
        final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec tab_spec ;

        for (int i = 0; i < tab_act.length; i++) {

                tab_spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tab_title[i]);
                tab_spec.setIndicator(tab_title[i],
                        getResources().getDrawable(tab_drawables[i]));
                tab_spec.setContent(new Intent(this, (Class<?>) tab_act[i]));
                tabHost.addTab(tab_spec);

        }
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            TabBarActivity.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new activity, screen 0, and get it to start your tab activity, screen 1 and screen 2, using intents. You can then change you manifest file so that you have your new activity marked as launcher by adding this code to the activity decleration.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

You will also need to remove that code from your current tab activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something the TabActivity would normally support.

You might be able to achieve the desired effect by adding a "dummy" tab:

```
public class TabBarActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Your Tab Titles
    String tab_title[] = { "", "Screen 1", "Screen 2"};

    // Your Tab Drawables for their states
    int tab_drawables[] = { R.drawable.tab_home_custom,
            R.drawable.tab_balance_custom};

    // Your Tab Activities
    Object tab_act[] = {Activity.class, TabB.class,TabC.class};

    // / TabHost setup
    final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec tab_spec ;

    for (int i = 0; i < tab_act.length; i++) {

            tab_spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tab_title[i]);
            if(i>0) tab_spec.setIndicator(tab_title[i],
                    getResources().getDrawable(tab_drawables[i]));
            tab_spec.setContent(new Intent(this, (Class<?>) tab_act[i]));
            tabHost.addTab(tab_spec);

    }
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        TabBarActivity.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

I'm not sure if this will create a blank tab button in the tab bar though

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want a splash screen with the app logo,you need to create another activity  and navigate to the tabActivity from that

```
public class splash2 extends Activity{


    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 2000;
    Intent intent;
    Runnable r;
    Handler handler;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashlayout2);

        //   startActivity(new Intent(splash2.this,splash1.class));
        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen

        handler = new Handler();

        r=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                intent = new Intent(splash2.this, TabBarActivity .class);
                //intent.setClass();
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }

        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, _splashTime);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(splash2.this, Main_menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_left2, R.anim.slide_out_left2 );
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and add the following tag to the activity tag of this activity instead of having those tags inside the TabBarActivity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

It will make this splash screen the default activity

Comment: I am reaching to the tabactivity screen from another login screen only. In that case what can I do?

Comment: can you post the screenshot of what you exactly want

Comment: I added the screen shot by editing the question. Once the app reach this specific screen it should show screen 0. Once the user click on the first tab only it should show screen 1.